# Difference between an XML "Fragment" and an XML "Document

Tags: xml

What is the difference between an XML "Fragment" and an XML "Document."?

Comment: http://mabdeen84.blogspot.com.tr/2009/12/difference-between-xml-document-xml.html and  https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=TqQSE1jFy68C&pg=PT200&lpg=PT200&dq=what+is+the+difference+between+an+xml+fragment+and+an+xml+document&source=bl&ots=ld9Jtyrlht&sig=1iE8aK5b8Gv6dwoEjiJ31ym6Lfc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju6YyE6uzKAhXJfxoKHeEsCN8Q6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20an%20xml%20fragment%20and%20an%20xml%20document&f=false

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An XML fragment is an XML document with **no single top-level root element**. To put it simple it is a part (fragment) of a well-formed xml document. (node) Where as a well-formed **xml document must have only one root element**.

Comment: What are the well formed rules for XML fragments? Can I view them in a browser?