# Getting value on XML string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

Hi I've been working on this asp.net webform written on c# and i'm currently
stock getting value on XML result encapsulated in a string. 
I know little about XML and here is my attemps.

i have this XML string

```
<Code>0</Code>
<responseData>
    <LotDetails>
        <DEVICE>OH503/E-ICAM</DEVICE>
        <DEVICE12NC>340000064194</DEVICE12NC>
        <CONTAINERNAME>MBP001012700</CONTAINERNAME>
        <PACKAGE>SOT1207</PACKAGE>
    </LotDetails>
</responseData>
```

and i need to get the value of  `<CONTAINERNAME>` 
in c# i have this code

```
string result = tmpVal.GetQueryResult(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queryname_CMSS"].ToString(), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paramnames_CMSS"].ToString(), LotID).InnerXml.ToString();
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(result);
            XmlNode idNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//responseData/LotDetails/CONTAINERNAME");
```

My code above returns me an error of `dditional information: There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 16.`
It looks like i'm not getting the root element on my XML result.
Would someone help me out with this?
Thank you in advance.
Hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: I ran your code and it returns the idNode like how its supposed to. Are you sure this xml is what you are dealing with? idNode.InnerText gives you the value. [Tested here as well. dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b7dXMe)

Comment: on doc.LoadXml(result); the error pop

Comment: how are you getting result populated ? Can you share the code that sets up result with your xml data ?

Comment: ow your right this is not the xml im getting i updated my question

Comment: it still return's error There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 16.  on loadXml part i'll update again my question

Comment: You can't have two root elements in your XML - and now you have <Code> and <responseData>.

Comment: what do you mean i did't get it

Comment: You do not have an XML string; [that's not XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310590/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize the xml that does not have a parent node like this,

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<parent>" + result + "</parent>");
    //doc.LoadXml($"<parent>{result}</parent>");

    XmlNode idNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//responseData/LotDetails/CONTAINERNAME");
```

Or you can use a method to [Parse XML without a parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115583/1390548).

Comment: Use the + sign instead of $ sign to concatenate the string.

Comment: Be aware that this won't work if the supplied XML includes an XML declaration or DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: Proper XML should have a parent node defined and in such case, this wouldnt be required. Since its a specific use-case, adding parent with two rootElements is being suggested. I totally agree with you @MichaelKay, If you are trying to work XML like this, you are most likely better off trying to get the source of XML corrected

Comment: why im not getting the parent it suppose to be like this<ResultMessage>
<Code>0</Code>
<responseData>
<LotDetails>
<DEVICE>OH503/E-ICAM</DEVICE>
<DEVICE12NC>340000064194</DEVICE12NC>
<CONTAINERNAME>MBP001012700</CONTAINERNAME>
<PACKAGE>SOT1207</PACKAGE>
</LotDetails>
</responseData>
</ResultMessage>

Comment: The root cause problem is with the very first line: **string result = tmpVal.GetQueryResult(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queryname_CMSS"].ToString(), System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paramnames_CMSS"].ToString(), LotID).InnerXml.ToString();** You need to get from the configuration file XML as XML data type, not the string.